# C# Interop with C DLL, how do I marshal a char array where length is returned from the function?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have to access a C DLL from C#. I don't have source for the DLL so I am stuck with the following function signature:

```
int func(unsigned char* instr, unsigned char* outstr, int inlength);
```

How do I declare the DllImport for this in C# so that .NET understands that the returned INT is the length of the outstr array. The output char* is not a C-style string. They are byte arrays and thus there can be zeroes embedded in the output.

```
[DllImport("the.dll")]
int func([In] string instr, [Out] ?????? outstr, int inlength);
```

EDIT: Please read carefully. The RETURN value is length of the outstr parameter.

Comment: `StringBuilder outstr`. Which needs to be [initialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_StringBuilder__ctor_System_Int32_) with `inlength` chars. And add `CharSet=Ansi` to the `DllImport`.

Comment: A c++ character array is in c# is a byte array terminated with a '\0'.  Characters in c# are a class with a private property that indicates if a character is one or two bytes.  Conversion can be done using Marshal.PtrToStringAuto or done automatically if you declare the type as a string.

Comment: @jdweng [`char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) is a struct (not class) that always uses 2 bytes for the character, [without](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs) any size variations.

Comment: The function requires you to guess at a byte[] that is sufficiently large, as stated by *inlength*.  There is no mechanism to truncate that byte[], it isn't marshaled at all and the native code directly accesses the memory allocated for the array.  Nice and fast.  If you want a perfectly trimmed byte[] afterwards then you have to create it yourself, Array.Copy() to shovel the data.  Ideally you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C API is less than ideal. The function can’t allocate a new buffer and return it, and doesn’t even take the length of the buffer.

API user (you) have to know in advance upper bound of how many bytes the function will write to that array, and supply output buffer of that size.

The DLL import itself is simple:

```
[DllImport( "the.dll" )]
int func( [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2 )] byte[] instr, [Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] outstr, int inlength );
```

If the function returns count of bytes written, call the function then resize the output array.

Comment: As far as I understand, it doesn't need the length of the `instr` because it will be zero terminated, and it does receive the length of `outstr` in `inlength`.

Comment: I'm well aware the function signature is less than ideal.

Comment: Usually, with one of those "call once to measure, call a second time to get the data", you pass a null or something on the first pass to indicate "Hey, just measure this for me".  Take a look at PInvoke.net to see if you can find an example of how this is done in other contexts

Comment: @Flydog57 If that's the case, my DLL import function is fine. OP needs to call it twice, first time pass null for outstr, they’ll receive required buffer length. Allocate a new byte array of that length, call second time.

Comment: @GSerg Don't you find strange the API designer named the length of `outstr` as `inlength`, as opposed to `outlength` ?

Comment: @Soonts Well, it's the length of the output buffer on the entry to the function, which is *in*. If it was named `outlength`, I would expect it to be `int*` and *receive* the length of the buffer `outstr` now points to. So it would be kind of off in any case.

Comment: @GSerg, there are plenty of APIs where the output length is not a pointer. You allocate the memory before you call the API and then tell the API what the maximum length of the buffer is.